Why won't my 09 Pontiac Vibe engine turn by hand?
Full disclosure - I don't actually know a lot about cars. I've taken a few heads off and replaced a piston, but under another's guidance. I mostly read and watch videos to try and figure things out.
I bought an automatic transmission 09 Pontiac Vibe GT with the 2.4 liter engine about a week ago (fairly cheap). It has sat for approximately four years in a garage shop. Supposedly, the engine blew and it was replaced with a salvage engine from a junkyard and then the final connections were not made (the mechanic died leaving it in an unknown state). I found that the VIN on the engine does not match the VIN on the car and I found junkyard markings on the engine and thus feel that the engine was legitimately replaced. The previous owner said he heard the motor run at the junkyard in the car it was pulled from. This jives with what I've found because why would someone go to the trouble of putting a broken motor in a good shell.
The biggest issue I could see when looking at to buy the car was that electrical components were not plugged in and there were a few missing parts (such as the radiator overflow and some bolts). I have replaced all missing parts and connected all electrical.
One spark plug had been left out of its cylinder for the past four years. I did put a borescope down each cylinder and it's very difficult to see but the one open cylinder does appear darker which could be rust.
Basically, it should now be ready to run. Before trying to turn over via the key, I wanted to turn it over by hand. I have had no luck as it won't budge. I thought initially it might have moved a degree or two, but I think I may have only tightened the bolt (it seems that locked up). I thought I might be able to rock it back and forth (turn clockwise and counterclockwise), but all that did was remove the bolt when I went counterclockwise. I have removed all belts from the crankshaft pulley to confirm that none of the accessories are actually locked up and preventing the crankshaft pulley from turning. I have dumped penetrating fluids into each of the spark plug holes and left it sit for several days.
I looked at the engine oil and it looks clean, honey gold as new oil does - which makes sense if the mechanic had just put new oil in before dropping the engine in.
I wouldn't think the timing would be off as the entire engine was pulled from the salvage car and supposedly ran in the junkyard. I don't see how the timing could be off.
I don't know the condition of the rods and bearings and have not taken a look under the valve cover. I understand that those could cause an issue. What is easy to check? Probably under the valve cover, but I'm not sure what I would be checking for. Any thoughts?
The only other thing I can think to try would be to remove the starter on the chance that it could be engaged with the flywheel thus preventing movement. Is that even a possibility?
Could the transmission be somehow engaged with the engine preventing it from turning? I wouldn't think so. I've only tried to turn the crankshaft with the car in park which I thought was the thing to do.
I'm just hoping that the rings aren't rusted to the cylinder. Supposedly it was garaged for four years so I wouldn't think it would have had a lot of moisture to get in it. But, I don't really know.
Anything else that anyone can think of that I could try before I junk it and move on? I just don't want to miss out on trying something I hadn't thought of.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

With no answers or comments here after 24 hours, I'll state the obvious: it's possible that you are underestimating the torque required to turn an engine by hand, and nothing is wrong. Rather than junk the car, wouldn't it be OK to just bloop the starter for a moment and see if the engine turns? You can remove the fuse for the ignition system if you're worried about the engine starting and running.

It could be that I I'm underestimating, but I owned two earlier Pontiac Vibes which I turned by hand and don't remember it being this difficult. I was just hoping there might be some other things which I could check before my last ditch efforts of putting an extension on my breaker bar or turning the key. My concern is that if it is rust in the cylinder preventing it from turning that I will destroy the rings with the last ditch effort. But, if all else has failed I will definitely try those things before just junking it. Thanks for ignition system fuse suggestion-didn't know that was a thing.
